# What is better to write/read to the USB or the SD card in terms of speed and reliability?

Tags: usb, sd-card, readwrite

I have been using both the SD card and the USB drive to save large files (videos) over a long period of time (weeks) and wondering what is best (and why). I have had problem with both (lags, corrupted files, etc) so I am wondering what I should be doing. I am using the RPi 3b+ (does this change with RPi 4 or with version of raspbian?)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I have had problem with both (lags, corrupted files, etc)

The usual reason for this is that the drive takes too much power; this *may* also cause enough problems to explain corruption on the SD card, which shouldn't happen *unless the power is being arbitrarily cut on a regular basis* (you need to shut the system down properly first).

Another factor with the USB is how it is formatted.  If this is a drive you only use with the Pi, it should be formatted `ext4` for best performance. If you need to share it with systems that can't read that, use `vfat`.  Avoid `ntfs` as this commonly leads to problems.